# Eclipse indigo Struts 2 installation

Tags: java

I'm new to J2EE, can anyone tell me how to install Struts 2 in Eclipse Indigo? I have tried many URLs, none of them were working. Could anyone, please, give me a valid URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't "install Struts 2 in Eclipse", you have a project that *uses* Struts 2 in Eclipse.

You either:

1. Get all the dependencies yourself and add them to your project, or
2. Use Maven and let the computer do what computers are good at.

For option 1, I'd recommended using the struts-blank application that ships with the distro. Optionally, you could read some of the [creating a Struts 2 application manually](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/create-struts-2-web-application-with-artifacts-in-web-inf-lib-and-use-ant-to-build-the-application.html), often useful for getting started.

For option 2, you could try using one of the Maven plugins for Eclipse (e.g., [m2eclipse](http://www.sonatype.org/m2eclipse)), and possibly following the [creating a Struts 2 project using Maven](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/create-struts-2-web-application-using-maven-to-manage-artifacts-and-to-build-the-application.html) docs.

Comment: i dnt know about maven.. as in netbeans we use struts 1.3. when we bulid new project, if i choose struts,it creates all the files for me.i', expecting the same..is it possible?

Comment: @meher Maven has nothing to do with NetBeans, Eclipse, or the Struts version. IIRC there is at least one Struts 2 Eclipse plugin that might generate "all files" (whatever that actually means), but there's much less of a *need* to have files auto-generated in S2, because there are less files. Start with a blank app, consider using a Maven archetype, or just create the file(s) manually. MyEclipse has an S2 plugin as well.